# Jquery if keyup else default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox whose value comes from database but if a user changes the value then this value needs to be used in a calculation.

```
$('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        var Cost = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

and

```
var cost = $('input.ecost1').val();
```

I need if `keyup` function for user enter value (first code example) else default database value (second code example). How can I write this if/else condition?

i need

```
 if ($('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        var Cost = $(this).val();
    }
}); ) 
else {
var cost = $('input.ecost1').val();
}
```

i know in if() code is wrong but above logic how to corrected

Comment: And what is wrong right now?

Comment: how to place if else condition to get one of value above i want if keyup than that value other wise dfault (below value)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this is what is required.

```
var valueFromDB = getValueFromDB(); //Your function for calling database
var Cost = 0;
$('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        Cost = $(this).val();
    }
    else{
        Cost = valueFromDB;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if-else in javascript works like this:

```
if(expression) {
    //do this if expression is true
} else {
    //do this if expression is false
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need for keyup what is condition i have to write.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the `else` if you provide a default value before you evaluate your input:

**UPDATE** as per comments below.

```
var Cost = 123; // default value;

$('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){

    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        Cost = this.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: according to your answer $('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){ this keyup function must but i need if keyup else default value

Comment: @NachiketChaudhary I have updated my answer. By initialising a default value `Cost` on page load for instance, any time the `keyup` function is then executed, a new value will replace the default `Cost`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you want?

```
var Cost = $('input.ecost1').val();
$('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        Cost = $(this).val();
    }
 }
```

Comment: according to your answer $('#ecost input.ecost').keyup(function(){ this keyup function must but i need if keyup else default value

Comment: then use the default value outside the handler, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, I have this problem also and I edit @onerror answer. It works well

```
var search = $("#teacher_year_filter").val();

$("#teacher_year_filter").on("keyup", function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        search = this.value
    }

    var table_1 = table1.column(3).search(search).draw();
});

var table_2 = table1.column(3).search(search).draw();
```

It will filter the default value in the input, and once we type (keyup), then it will filter using the current input.